# Echoing javascript with events and function calls with parameters in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo, quotes

I want to echo the following in PHP:

```
echo "<td><p style='visibility: hidden' id='joindata$rowindex'>$joindata</p><a style='visibility: visible;' onclick='toggleDisplay('joindata$rowindex'); toggleDisplay('showjoindata$rowindex')' id='showjoindata$rowindex'>Show</a></td>";
```

But it is not echoing due to the nested ' ' Any Ideas how I can echo HTML elements which have events which call javascript functions which have parameters in PHP would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use double-quotes to delimit your attribute values, and escape them in your PHP string:

```
echo "<td><p style=\"visibility: hidden\" id=\"joindata$rowindex\">$joindata</p><a style=\"visibility: visible;\" onclick=\"toggleDisplay('joindata$rowindex'); toggleDisplay('showjoindata$rowindex')\" id=\"showjoindata$rowindex\">Show</a></td>";
```

Or, you could separate behaviour from content and just add the event handlers dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some double quotes, Try this:

```
echo "<td><p style=\"visibility: hidden\" id=\"joindata".$rowindex."\">$joindata</p><a style=\"visibility: visible;\" onclick=\"toggleDisplay('joindata".$rowindex."'); toggleDisplay('showjoindata".$rowindex."')\" id=\"showjoindata".$rowindex."\">Show</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP have best performance and scalability when you separate the views from the data. However in this case you could do:

```
<td>
    <p style="visibility: hidden" id="joindata<?php echo $rowindex; ?>">
        <?php echo $joindata; ?>
    </p>
    <a style="visibility:visible" onclick="toggleDisplay('joindata<?php echo $rowindex; ?>'); toggleDisplay('showjoindata<?php echo $rowindex; ?>')" id="showjoindata<?php echo $rowindex; ?>">Show</a>
</td>
```

Also take a look on the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) docs to avoid hard-coding the javascript functions. Your app will run faster.